# Iterative Red-Black Tree (dynamic stack)

Tags: c++, tree, memory-management

I've completely reworked the previous code, posted [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/110461/memory-management-for-red-black-tree), so that it is a bit more correct regarding dynamic memory management, and also a bit more true to the object-oriented paradigm.

```
/** A program for Red-Black Tree manipulation: insertion and value retrieval.
  * All position relations (first, last, previous, next) are in-order.
  */

class RBTree {
    struct Node {
        enum class Colour : bool { RED, BLACK };
        int value;
        Node *left, *right, *parent;
        Colour colour;
    public:
        Node* getGrandparent() const;
        Node* getUncle() const;
        void setLeft(Node*);
        void setRight(Node*);
    };
    class Iterator {
        class Stack {
            Node **buffer;
            int size, top;
        private:
            void resize();
        public: // Member 'buffer' is initialized like this because the program doesn't catch/handle exceptions.
            Stack() : size(16), buffer(new Node*[size]), top(0) {}
            void push(Node*);
            Node* pop();
            Node* peek();
            void clear();
            bool isEmpty() const;
            ~Stack() { delete[] buffer; } // ?
        public:
            Stack(const Stack&);
            Stack(Stack&&);
            Stack& operator = (const Stack&);
            Stack& operator = (Stack&&);
        };
        Stack stack;
        const RBTree* const tree; // Once set, neither the reference nor the referenced object's attributes can be modified.
        Node* pointer;
    public:
        Iterator(const RBTree*);
        void first();
        void next();
        void last();
        void reset();
        void to(Node*);
        Node* getNode() const;
        bool operator != (const Iterator&) const;
    };
    Node *root;
    Iterator iterator;
private:
    void attachValue(int);
    void resolve();
    void rotateLeft(Node*);
    void rotateRight(Node*);
    void setRoot(Node*);
    void deleteTree();
public:
    RBTree() : root(nullptr), iterator(this) {}
    bool insertValue(int);
    Node* findValue(int);
    bool printTree() const;
    ~RBTree() { deleteTree(); }
public: // This section ensures that tree can neither be copied nor initialized with another tree, only built with insertion.
    RBTree(const RBTree&) = delete;
    RBTree(RBTree&&) = delete;
    RBTree& operator = (const RBTree&) = delete;
    RBTree& operator = (RBTree&&) = delete;
};

// TREE // public: //

// Retruns {false} if value already exists.
bool RBTree::insertValue(int p_value) {
if (findValue(p_value) == nullptr) {
        attachValue(p_value);
        resolve();
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}

// Returns {nullptr} if value doesn't exist.
RBTree::Node* RBTree::findValue(int p_value) {
    Node *node = root, *parent = nullptr;
    while (node != nullptr) {
        if (p_value < node->value) {
            parent = node;
            node = node->left;
        }
        else if (p_value > node->value) {
            parent = node;
            node = node->right;
        }
        else
            return node;
    }
    if (parent != nullptr)
        iterator.to(parent);
    return nullptr;
}

bool RBTree::printTree() const {
    if (root != nullptr) {
        // print using in-order iteration
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;

}

// TREE // private: //

// Attaches the given value under the current node (referenced by member 'iterator').
void RBTree::attachValue(int p_value) {
    Node *node = new Node;
    (*node) = { p_value, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, Node::Colour::RED };
    if (root == nullptr) {
        root = node;
        return;
    }
    Node *parent = iterator.getNode();
    iterator.reset();
    if (p_value < parent->value)
        parent->setLeft(node);
    else
        parent->setRight(node);
    iterator.to(node);
}

// Resolves the invalid states.
void RBTree::resolve() {
    int case_number = 1;
    Node *node = iterator.getNode();
    iterator.reset();
    if (node == nullptr)
        node = root;
    do {
        switch (case_number) {
            case 1: {
                if (node->parent == nullptr) {
                    node->colour = Node::Colour::BLACK;
                    return;
                }
            }
            case 2: {
                if (node->parent->colour == Node::Colour::BLACK)
                    return;
            }
            case 3: {
                Node *uncle = node->getUncle();
                if (uncle != nullptr && uncle->colour == Node::Colour::RED) {
                    Node *grandparent = node->getGrandparent();
                    node->parent->colour = Node::Colour::BLACK;
                    uncle->colour = Node::Colour::BLACK;
                    grandparent->colour = Node::Colour::RED;
                    node = grandparent;
                    break;
                }
            }
            case 4: {
                Node *grandparent = node->getGrandparent(), *parent = node->parent;
                if (node == parent->right && parent == grandparent->left) {
                    rotateLeft(parent);
                    node = node->left;
                }
                else if (node == parent->left && parent == grandparent->right) {
                    rotateRight(parent);
                    node = node->right;
                }
            }
            case 5: {
                Node *grandparent = node->getGrandparent(), *parent = node->parent;
                parent->colour = Node::Colour::BLACK;
                grandparent->colour = Node::Colour::RED;
                if (node == parent->left)
                    rotateRight(grandparent);
                else
                    rotateLeft(grandparent);
                node = parent;
                break;
            }
        }
    } while (case_number);
}

RBTree::Node* RBTree::Node::getGrandparent() const {
    if (parent != nullptr)
        return parent->parent;
    else
        return nullptr;
}

RBTree::Node* RBTree::Node::getUncle() const {
    Node *grandparent = getGrandparent();
    if (this == grandparent->left)
        return grandparent->right;
    else
        return grandparent->left;
}

void RBTree::rotateLeft(Node *p_node) {
    Node *node = p_node;
    Node *right_left = p_node->right->left;
    if (p_node == root) // If root is the pivot, update the root info.
        setRoot(p_node->right);
    p_node = p_node->right;
    if (node->parent != nullptr)
        node->parent->setRight(node->right);
    node->right->setLeft(node);
    node->setRight(right_left);

}

void RBTree::rotateRight(Node *p_node) {
    Node *node = p_node;
    Node *left_right = p_node->left->right;
    if (p_node == root) // If root is the pivot, update the root info.
        setRoot(p_node->right);
    p_node = p_node->left;
    if (node->parent != nullptr)
        node->parent->setLeft(node->left);
    node->left->setRight(node);
    node->setLeft(left_right);
}

void RBTree::setRoot(Node *p_root) {
    root = p_root;
    root->parent = nullptr;
}

void RBTree::deleteTree() {
    Node *node;
    for (Iterator i(this); (node = i.getNode()) != root; i.next())
        delete node;
    delete root;
}

// NODE: Ensures the proper connection. //

void RBTree::Node::setLeft(Node *p_left) {
    left = p_left;
    if (p_left != nullptr)
        p_left->parent = this;
}

void RBTree::Node::setRight(Node *p_right) {
    right = p_right;
    if (p_right != nullptr)
        p_right->parent = this;
}

// ITERATOR //

RBTree::Iterator::Iterator(const RBTree* p_tree) : tree(p_tree), pointer(p_tree->root) {}

// Traverses to the first node (leftmost).
void RBTree::Iterator::first() {
    if (pointer != nullptr) {
        while (true) {
            if (pointer != nullptr) {
                stack.push(pointer);
                pointer = pointer->left;
            }
            else {
                pointer = stack.peek();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

// Traverses to next node in-order.
void RBTree::Iterator::next() {
    if (pointer != nullptr) {
        if (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            pointer = stack.pop();
            if (pointer->right != nullptr) {
                pointer = pointer->right;
                first();
            }
        }
    }
}

// Traverses to the last node (rightmost).
void RBTree::Iterator::last() {
    pointer = tree->root;
    if (pointer != nullptr)
        while (pointer->right != nullptr)
            pointer = pointer->right;
    stack.clear();
}

// Returns to the first node.
void RBTree::Iterator::reset() {
    pointer = tree->root;
    stack.clear();
    first();
}

// Traverses to the given node. Stores {nullptr} if the node cannot be found. // ??
void RBTree::Iterator::to(Node *p_node) {
    if (p_node == tree->root) {
        pointer = p_node;
        return;
    }
    reset();
    while (pointer != p_node)
        next();
}

RBTree::Node* RBTree::Iterator::getNode() const {
    return pointer;
}

bool RBTree::Iterator::operator != (const Iterator& p_iterator) const {
    return pointer != p_iterator.pointer ? true : false;
}

// STACK //

// Doubles the stack size.
void RBTree::Iterator::Stack::resize() {
    Node **temporary = new Node*[size <<= 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < top; i++)
        temporary[i] = buffer[i];
    delete[] buffer;
    buffer = temporary;
}

// Copy constructor.
RBTree::Iterator::Stack::Stack(const Stack& p_stack) : size(p_stack.size), top(p_stack.top), buffer(new Node*[p_stack.size]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < top; i++)
        buffer[i] = p_stack.buffer[i];
}

// Move constructor.
RBTree::Iterator::Stack::Stack(Stack&& p_stack) : size(p_stack.size), top(p_stack.top), buffer(p_stack.buffer) {
    p_stack.buffer = nullptr;
}

// Copy assignment operator.
RBTree::Iterator::Stack& RBTree::Iterator::Stack::operator = (const Stack& p_stack) {
    if (p_stack.buffer == this->buffer)
        return *this;
    size = p_stack.size;
    top = p_stack.top;
    Node** temporary = new Node*[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < top; i++)
        temporary[i] = p_stack.buffer[i];
    delete[] buffer;
    buffer = temporary;
    return *this;
}

// Move assignment operator.
RBTree::Iterator::Stack& RBTree::Iterator::Stack::operator = (Stack&& p_stack) {
    if (p_stack.buffer == this->buffer)
        return *this;
    delete[] buffer;
    buffer = p_stack.buffer;
    p_stack.buffer = nullptr;
    return *this;
}

void RBTree::Iterator::Stack::push(Node *p_node) {
    if (top == size)
        resize();
    buffer[top++] = p_node;
}

RBTree::Node* RBTree::Iterator::Stack::pop() {
    return isEmpty() ? nullptr : buffer[--top];
}

RBTree::Node* RBTree::Iterator::Stack::peek() {
    return isEmpty() ? nullptr : buffer[top - 1];
}

void RBTree::Iterator::Stack::clear() {
    top = 0;
}

bool RBTree::Iterator::Stack::isEmpty() const {
    return top == 0 ? true : false;
}

#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;

int main() {
    RBTree tree;
    int choice = 0;
    cout << "\nOptions: \n\n 1 Insert value.\n 2 Find value.\n\n 0 Exit.\n\nChoice: ";
    cin >> choice;
    while (choice != 0) {
        switch (choice) {
            case 1: {
                cout << "\nValue = ";
                cin >> choice;
                if (tree.insertValue(choice))
                    cout << "\n > Insertion successful.\n";
                else
                    cout << "\n > Insertion failed.\n";
                break;
            }
            case 2: {
                cout << "\nValue = ";
                cin >> choice;
                if (tree.findValue(choice) != nullptr)
                    cout << "\n > Value found.\n";
                else
                    cout << "\n > Value not found.\n";
                break;
            }
            case 3: {
                if (tree.printTree())
                    cout << "\n > Print unsuccessful.\n";
                else
                    cout << "\n > Print failed.\n";
                break;
            }
            case 0: {
                return 0;
            }
            default: {
                cout << "\n > Invalid option.\n";
            }
        }
        cout << "\nOptions: \n\n 1 Insert node.\n 2 Find node.\n\n 0 Exit.\n\nChoice: ";
        cin >> choice;
    }
}
```

The `printTree()` function is a stub, I'm still looking for an appropriate algorithm that utilizes the in-order traversal. That's not a part of this review, for it is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33769837/binary-tree-iterative-inorder-print), in detail.

I am looking for a confirmation that the code has sufficiently improved since the previous version, guided by the answers I was given in that post regarding encapsulation, memory management, etc... Also I would appreciate if you could point out if I've done anything wrong while applying those critiques.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What is an Iterator?**

An iterator is a very powerful concept in the world of C++. At its core, iterator is just a set of required operations, but when every iterator-like object adheres to those concepts, you can open up the wonderful world of generic programming.

Writing a container that has iterators that adhere to the standard means that I can be completely agnostic to whatever it is you're doing under the hood. If I want to iterate over everything in your map, I just do that:

```
for (auto const& item : map) { ... }
```

I bring this up because `RBTree::Iterator` meets almost none of the concepts of even the lowest level of iterator, [`InputIterator`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/111060/iterative-red-black-tree-dynamic-stack). Those operations are: `i != j`, `*i`, `i->member`, `++i`, `(void)i++`, `*i++`. Although a RedBlack Tree should really support a [`BidirectionalIterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator).

In this case, `Iterator` (which should be spelled `iterator`) should really just be a thin wrapper for `Node*`. There is no `Stack` necessary (indeed, I am unsure what `Iterator::Stack` is for).

```
class iterator {
    Node* cur;

public:
    ...
};
```

Equality, inequality, and dereference are trivial operations. Since you have the `Node*`, and thus know the node's parent, left, and right children, that is enough to figure out what the next and previous nodes are to this one, which should be spelled:

```
iterator& operator++() { /* next */; return *this; }
iterator& operator--() { /* prev */; return *this; }
```

To get you started, the easy case for "next" is if our current node has a right child:

```
iterator& operator++() {
    if (cur->right) {
        cur = cur->right;
        while (cur->left) {
            cur = cur->left;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    else {
        ...
    }
}
```

It is very important to write your iterators to work the way that users expect iterators to work. I cannot stress this enough.

Lastly, you should **not** have a *member* iterator. That doesn't make sense. An iterator is for iterating. The tree should have a single member: the `root`.

**Consistency**

Once we have a working iterator, let's keep the interface consistent with other containers. To start with, we need the typical container skeleton:

```
iterator begin();
iterator end();
```

Then, `find()` should return an `iterator`

```
iterator find(int);
```

which should be compared to `end()` to see if we've found anything. And `printTree()` should really look like:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const RBTree& );
```

Since `std::cout << tree;` is natural, and easily allows you to write your tree to other kinds of streams.

**Why not copyable?**

Why is your class neither copyable nor moveable? At the very least, writing the move operations should be trivial:

```
RBTree(RBTree&& rhs)
: root(rhs.root) {
    rhs.root = nullptr;
}
```

No reason not to support it. Copying will involve a deep copy, but that's less complicated than any other operation for the tree. You don't need to figure out colouring! Just copy.

**Principle of Least Surprise**

I think most people would be surprised that `findValue()` mutates your `RBTree`! When I said in your previous post to factor out the common logic so they call a common function, I meant just that - not to create a new member to store the intermediate data!

This isn't just a questionable solution because it's surprising. This also means you can't write `find()` as a `const` member function, which means that a `const RBTree` is useless.

Furthermore, we have `resolve()`, which is only called here:

```
bool RBTree::insertValue(int p_value) {
    if (findValue(p_value) == nullptr) {
        attachValue(p_value);
        resolve();  // <===
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

It should be up to `attachValue()`'s job to keep the map in a consistent state. Otherwise, you could simply forget to call `resolve()` and now your tree is broken.

Comment: @StefanStanković There's no need for "redeeming" yourself. Nobody here is think less of you as a human being for writing non-perfect code. And nobody left the womb with perfect knowledge of C++ either. That's what we're here for.